# ¿Como termino de resolver mi petición con fetch? (utilizando Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promesas, fetch

Muy Buenas

Estoy empezando a trabajar con APIs utilizando **fetch**.

La cuestión es que al responder lo hace de una manera que no descifro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esto yo quiero obtener solamente lo que esta dentro de **[[PromiseValue]]**, ya que ese sería el JSON.

Código de la petición:

```
var services = {};

services.getPopularMovies = () => fetch(URL_NEW_MOVIES)
    .then(res => res.json());

export default services;
```

Componente Vue.js

```
  methods: {
    populares() {
      let res = config.getPopularMovies();
      this.popularMovies = res;
    }
  }
```

Comment: usa como guia : https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `config.getPopularMovies()` devuelve una promesa, la cual devuelve un resultado esperado. Y tienes que pasarlo a la opción `popularMovies` para imprimirlo en tu html rederizado por Vue.

Etonces tu codigo seria de este modo:

```
methods: {
    async populares() {
      let ajax = await config.getPopularMovies();
      this.popularMovies = ajax.results;
    }
  }
```

Y tu html seria así:

```html
<div v-for="movie in popularMovies">
{{ movie.name }}
</div>
```

Comment: Al implementarlo me imprime las propiedades del array (consolo.log luego de la asignación). Dado que es asíncrono me lo muestra vació.

Comment: Y lo hago fuera del then()al console.log(). En cambio si lo hago dentro me imprime el array de esta forma: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]

Comment: Ese array son los resultados que arroja el fetch, y tu tienes que manejarlos

Comment: Claro, pero esto es dentro del then(). Si o si tendré que manejaros ahí dentro no?

Comment: @GonzaloM modifique mi respuesta. Puedes usar el método implementando `async/await` de ese modo

Comment: Perfecto, funciona como esperaba que lo hiciera. Ahora, esto es lo normal cuando se hacen peticiones en un componente en vue? (Excluyendo el uso de Vuex)

Comment: @GonzaloM Usando ecmascript como sintaxis de javascript, si. `async/await` facilita el uso de peticiones basadas en promesas. Pero usando vanilla JS es como te había mostrado anteriormente